# How can I export the list of open Chrome tabs?

Tags: chrome-for-android

Chrome's sync feature isn't picking up all of the tabs open on my Android phone.

Are the tabs stored in a file somewhere that I can access?

My intention is to export the list of tabs so that I could run a factory reset on the device.

Running Android 4.3

Comment: chrome://history/syncedTabs for anyone whose sync feature is working btw

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use the Remote Devices feature in the Chrome debugger to connect to Chrome on the device and access the tabs. Just expand the list of tabs visible to get the full list and then highlight & copy everything shown (including the URLs) to the clipboard:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

I just managed to export ~400 tabs this way.

Comment: wanted to mention that the chrome debugger list will shorten the urls if they are too long, so instead of copy-pasting, you can get the url's directly using the method in [Louis Maddox's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/193858/73909)

Comment: @woojoo666: It looks like things in Chrome have changed and now Louis's answer also truncates the end of many URLs. Looks like any URL over 100 characters -- which in my case it about 50% of all my open tabs -- will be missing its ending.

Comment: @peterflynn still works for me. Just exported a url that was 432 characters long. Just to make sure, you're opening the dev tools in a pop-out window, going to the "remote devices" pane, then using ctrl-shift-J to open a second dev-tools window, and then using the script provided [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56635/how-can-i-export-the-list-of-open-chrome-tabs/177760?noredirect=1#comment253406_193858), correct?

Comment: What is the minimum required Android version to do this?

Answer (score 52):

*Update October 2022*: As per [Remote debug Android devices](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/), the `chrome://inspect/#devices` page has replaced the `Remote devices` debugger panel, breaking the JS in this answer and similar ones.

---

Just joined this StackExchange to show some appreciation for [Jeremy's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/177760/258950) above, and also add the few lines of JS I used to export the tabs list (since copying with the cursor isn't ideal!)

As Jeremy said, select `Remote devices` under `More tools` on Chrome devtools `⋮` icon (top right of the panel):

[image]

- set up USB debugging on your phone (under `Settings`⇒`Developer options`, root not required)

  - note that you must enable the `Developer options` menu, it's hidden by default to protect users
  - on my phone this required tapping multiple times on the build number under `Settings`⇒`About Device`
- once this is done, plug your USB in and allow MTP connection
- when the Chrome devtools remote device panel is open, the phone will then request to allow USB debugging

  - you can opt to always trust the computer

[image]

Now the device is connected,

- open a 2nd devtools view on the devtools view from which you selected `Remote devices` to be able to retrieve the list of tabs using JavaScript

  - note that you must have devtools in pop-out mode (use the vertical ellipsis symbol in the top right of the panel) to be able to get this up, otherwise Command+Option+J(MAC) `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`J`(WINDOWS) will just close the first devtools panel.
- expand the list from the first few items to all tabs by clicking 'Show more'
- to script against the list, use the following few lines of code [entered in the console of the 2nd devtools window]

[image]

To export a list of all URLs open on Chrome for Android, I chose to just make the list into a markdown formatted text string and copy it to the clipboard

```
let bookmarkList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.widget>.vbox'))
  .map(e => e.shadowRoot)
  .map(e => e && e.querySelector('.device-page-list'))
  .find(e => e);

let bookmarks = Array.from(bookmarkList.querySelectorAll('.vbox'))
  .map(e => `[${e.querySelector('.device-page-title').innerHTML}](${e.querySelector('x-link').innerHTML})`);

copy(bookmarks.join('\n'));
```

You will then have a list on your clipboard looking like this:

```
[How can I export the list of open Chrome tabs? - Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56635/how-can-i-export-the-list-of-open-chrome-tabs)
[Get Started with Remote Debugging Android Devices  |  Tools for Web Developers  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/)
[How To Enable USB Debugging On Your Android Phone](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/mobile/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-android-phone/)
[Configure On-Device Developer Options | Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options.html)
...
```

Comment: Chrome changed, `tabs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div /deep/ div /deep/ div /deep/ div /deep/ div /deep/ .device-page-list .vbox'), s => ({name: s.querySelector('.device-page-title').textContent, url: s.querySelector('.devtools-link')._href}))` will work now

Comment: Note that using this technique, any URL over 100 characters long will have its ending cut off.

Comment: @peterflynn still works for me. I just exported a url that was 432 chars. Make sure you're using the script that diamotte provided

Comment: Can this be used to get a previous tabs state?

Comment: What is the minimum required Android version?

Comment: It changed again. For Chrome Version "73.0.3683.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)":

`tabs = Array.from(document.querySelector('div /deep/ div /deep/ div /deep/ div /deep/ div /deep/ div /deep/ div.vbox.flex-auto').shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.devices-view .device-page-list .vbox'), s => ({name: s.querySelector('.device-page-title').textContent, url: s.querySelector('.device-page-url .devtools-link').getAttribute('href')}))` (I could not access the final shadow-root via a selector, but had to use the `.shadowRoot` property of its host element instead. Not exactly sure why, but hey, unsupported.

Comment: Just in case anyone else is having trouble, I was having issues running some of these scripts (it was hammering the kernel's USB stack with 100% usage over 10+ minutes before I stopped it). The best way I found was to select the parent HTML element in the chrome dev tools inspector (use the cursor button in the top left of the nested dev tools window to select a random item in the list and then select the parent element) and then right click -> "Edit as HTML" -> copy into another text file. Then it was easier and a lot faster to adapt the above scripts to work on that local HTML copy (or BASH)

Comment: The script was broken for me in Chrome 79 (`/deep/` is deprecated and the way that CSS selects into shadow-roots has changed) so I updated it, using the least specific selector that got the job done. Hopefully it will work for several Chrome versions to come.

Comment: As of Chrome 81, "Remote Devices" is accessible from chrome://inspect/#devices instead of in Dev Tools. That makes it a bit easier, no need to open Dev-Tools-on-Dev-Tools.

Comment: To get the full names/URLs, not truncated to 100 chars (as in [@priorincantatio's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214670)): Open Dev Tools on that Remote Devices page and edit the "inspect.js" source file in browser to remove the truncation code (currently it's `text = text.substring(0, 100) + '\u2026';`), save it, then [re]connect the device to [re]load the URLs.

Then copy the URLs list to your clipboard using the latest valid code snippet (currently it's [in the Gist above](https://gist.github.com/codebling/3b7bfdbfbabf7bc17d8566b92854b4c3#gistcomment-3291314)).

Comment: Following @BenJ's idea — I added a line of code: `window.savedPages.push(page)` to save the page data directly to a global array, without going through HTML. The line is added in inspect.js, in populateRemoteTargets, right before `const row = addTargetToList(page, pageList, ['name', 'url']);`

Answer (score 43):

tl;dr:

- have the Android command line tools installed on a development machine, and USB debugging enabled on your device. The device does not need to be rooted
- `adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote`
- `wget -O tabs.json http://localhost:9222/json/list`

Details:

If you have the [Android command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads) installed on a development machine, and have enabled USB debugging on your Android device, then you can do the following:

- Execute `adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote` on your development machine.

  Chrome instances expose access to a debugging protocol via a unix domain socket with the [abstract address](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/linux/SocketAbstractNamespace) "`chrome_devtools_remote`". The above `adb` command forwards requests made to port 9222 on your development machine, onwards to that unix domain socket. (You can get a list of all the unix domain sockets on the Android device by typing `adb shell cat /proc/net/unix`.)

  Using this, we can run `wget` or `curl` (or indeed, a browser) and retrieve information from the mobile device's chrome instance.
- Debugging information is provided as JSON data over HTTP. A JSON file listing the open tabs can be got by executing `wget -O tabs.json http://localhost:9222/json/list`.

  (Other endpoints of the API can be found at https://github.com/buggerjs/bugger-daemon/blob/master/README.md#api.)

See [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging-legacy) for more details on enabling USB debugging, and [here](https://www.girish.in/how-remote-debugging-works-in-chrome/) for an overview of how it works.

Comment: `wget -O - -q https://git.io/Jvfzk | bash`

Comment: +1 as I find this answer more useful than the hack of executing javascript code to retrieve the list.

Comment: THIS is the way. Be sure to have Chrome actually open on your device and displaying (i.e. don't let the screen go to sleep)

Comment: I've created a automated php script to take on this task. It saves the json for further processing and a markdown list of links to view. Find it at https://github.com/machinateur/android-chrome-tab-transfer. It saved me from copying about 450 tabs to my new phone.

Comment: For windows I downloaded the SDK (https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools), extracted the zip from the download, the cd into the dir and used the adb.exe. Had to turn my device to MIDI and then press ok on the allow dialogue on my phone. Then ran the above commands in PowerShell and got the tabs file.

Comment: Once I got adb setup this worked a lot better than getting it from the devtools with the added truncated URLs issue.  It did take some effort getting a new setup on Windows trying the command line tools only rather than installing the full Android Studio.

Comment: I had to unplug and re-plug my USB cable to get `adb` to work (verify with `adb devices`).  Then this worked brilliantly.

Comment: I just ran "adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote" from Android SDK adb shell on my laptop. Then loaded "http://localhost:9222/json/list" in my laptop chrome, copied the text to notepad and saved with ".json" file extension. Then opened that in MS Excel and filtered out just the url list from the json data. Worked like a charm. Thanks! +1+1+1

Comment: Created a PowerShell script that makes it sligthly easier to get the file with tabs and convert it to CSV.  Supports UTF8 encoding which is critical for Cyrillic, German, French, etc. Please find it here: https://github.com/ampil/export-android-tabs . Inspired by this thread!

Answer (score 15):

I came across this solution when I was looking to recover tabs that had been permanently closed after my browser crashed one day. In order to access the information you require, **your device needs to be rooted** so you can run a file explorer app with access to the root files installed on your device. [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) or [Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer) are my recommendations.

1. Navigate to the root folder of your device (the protected system partition) → select `DATA` → select `com.android.chrome`.
2. There are several places where you may find information about your current tabs.

   1. The first folder to check is `app_tabs`, then `0`. In this folder there should be a file called `tab_state` which contains a list of all your current tabs.
   2. There are also other files in this folder called `tab3`, `tab4`, etc. that contain info about current tabs.
   3. IMO, you need a special "text editor / sql editor" to read the content of some of these files as the encoding is different.
3. Next place to look is `/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/`. In this folder you'll find a file called `History`. Depending on your situation, you may find a good list of recent site visits here.
4. Finally, navigate to the `Sync Data folder`. In here, you will find the information that's being synced to Google (and this should include all the tabs you currently have synced on other devices).

   - In the file `SyncData.sqlite3`, you'll also find a history of all your Google searches (which I sometimes find to be an interesting read).
   - You'll need an Sqlite3 data browser [program](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) on your PC in order to read this file.  The app should be able to export to a highly usable `.CSV` or `.XLS` file that you can open in **MS Excel**.

This could be helpful to someone I assume.

Comment: Re "special text editor" for `tab_state0`: `strings tab_state0 | grep -oh "http.*$"` should do the trick to give you a list of urls. I used that also in [How to recover open opera tabs from backup data after phone bricked?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225700/96334).

Answer (score 4):

The most recent answer by [simonsan](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214518/300669) is not working on my current Chrome build `75.0.3770.100`.
I don't have the `vbox` class that is used in every script posted, so I managed to write a code that is working now:

```
tabs = document.querySelectorAll('#devices div /deep/ div /deep/ div /deep/ div /deep/ .row')
str = '';
for (i=0;i<tabs.length;i++){
  if (tabs[i].querySelector('.name').innerText != null){
    str += '- ['+tabs[i].querySelector('.name').innerText + '] (' + tabs[i].querySelector('.url').innerText +  ')\n'
  } else {
    console.log(tabs[i])
  }
}
```

I've found  [Louis Maddox](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/193858/300669)'s post and *screenshots* very useful to decipher his script  so here is mine with the updated tree.

[image: screenshot]

---

Anyway the solutions proposed to overcome the 100 char cap didn't work for me therefore I decided to edit the `inspect.js` from the source following these steps:

1. Download the [chrome-pak-customizer](https://github.com/myfreeer/chrome-pak-customizer#usage-windows-only) and unzip it.
2. From `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\75.0.3770.100` (where `75.0.3770.100` is the name of the build) make a copy of the `resources.pak` in your Documents folder, drag the copy and drop it on the `unpack.bat` in the unzipped folder.
3. In `\document\resources_unpaked\` take the `11208.js` and open it.
4. On the line 537 or by looking for `100` there are these lines

```
  let text = value ? String(value) : '';
  if (text.length > 100) {
    text = text.substring(0, 100) + '\u2026';
  }

changing the 100 to 300 should be enough, it may cuts some google search links but mine where still working.
```

5. Save the file and in the same folder drag the `pak_index.ini` and drop it on the `pak.bat`. now the `resource.pak` in `\documents\` has been updated with the changes.
6. Make a backup of `resource.pak` because you never know, close Chrome and replace the orginal with the updated version.

Now the script will show up to 300 chars for the urls.

Comment: Really nice! How did you find out that was the file 11208.js that you should edit? I am using another version of chrome and I dont have this file...

Comment: I figured an easier way: just to edit the inspect.js direct on chrome.

Comment: @juanora: how did you manage to edit it directly from chrome? Btw I don't remember but I guess I've setup the file research to look for "100" inside the files, a this point few file should popup

Comment: thanks for you answer. I tried searching for 100, substring, etc... No success... Please check this to see how to change it directly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5506786/3375218

Comment: Thanks!
Ok I'm sorry I don't know what was I as thinking: look for this '\u2026'

Comment: A [rejected edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/226241) made a suggestion that `11208.js` is no longer available in Chrome v80

Answer (score 3):

This workaround will give you a text file with individual URLs for all tabs you have open in Chrome for Android.

1. As mentioned in this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56635/96277) by [Michael](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/100477/michael), you have to grab the file that contains the current tabs. Using a root explorer on the device, grab this file and move it to your choice of folder in windows: `/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_tabs/0/tab_state`
2. Install [GNU Tools for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)
3. Sometimes there's a weird arrow-character in the file that screws up the script. If you run the script and it truncates part of the file, look at the last character and it'll probably be that weird arrow character. Find/replace it in the original file. Once it's gone, the script will run fine. It looks like this: `-->`
4. Go to command line prompt (go to "Run" or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and type `cmd`) and navigate to the folder which contains `sed.exe` (wherever you installed it in step 2.)
5. You'll probably want to move the original file (`tab_state`) to the same folder containing `sed.exe`. It'll make everything easier. Once you've done that, run this script:

   ```
   sed -i "s/.\{6\}http/\r\n\r\nhttp/g" tab_state
   ```
6. This will modify the file with all of the URLs formatted correctly. Open the file as a text file and then copy and paste the contents into a Word document or some other location. For some reason, if you don't copy and paste the data out, when you save the file it erases all of the line breaks/carriage returns. If things screw up, just start over and do it again. When it's all said and done, you should have a file that contains a list of links to all the tabs you had open before.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be root or Chrome to read `/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_tabs/0/tab_state0`

You can use this [dirtycow exploit](https://github.com/tukushan/CVE-2016-5195-runas) on vulnerable devices to become Chrome and get `tab_state0` from an attached device:

```
make root
adb shell
run-as com.android.chrome
chmod 711 /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_tabs/0
chmod 644 /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_tabs/0/tab_state0
exit
cp /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_tabs/0/tab_state0 /sdcard/
exit
adb pull /sdcard/tab_state0
```

Once you have access to `tab_state0`, extract the URLs:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -a -o 'http[[:print:]]*' tab_state0
```

Answer (score 3):

Instructions for Brave! You can replace the code in the console from [Louis Maddox](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/193858/300436) with this one, this is working as of today `Brave Version 1.0.0 Chromium: 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.
Remark: You can open a new console window of the remote devices window if you activate the remote device window and press `Ctrl+Shift+J`

```
tabs = Array.from(document.querySelector('div /deep/ div /deep/ div /deep/ div /deep/ div /deep/ div /deep/ div.vbox.flex-auto').shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.devices-view .device-page-list .vbox'), s => ({name: s.querySelector('.device-page-title').textContent, url: s.querySelector('.device-page-url .devtools-link').getAttribute('href')}))

str = ' ';

tabs.forEach(e => {
    str += '- ['+ e.name + '](' + e.url +')\n';
})
copy(str)
```

Then you can paste all your tabs in a textfile.

If you want to open all the tabs on your actual device replace the `tabs.forEach`-part with

```
tabs.forEach(e => {
    window.open(e.url, '_blank');
})
```

Don't try that with too many open tabs on your device, though.

I added this after the `tabs` part to manually synchronize opened tabs (brave still missing this feature and I had 650 opened tabs on my mobile device) in charges of 50 tabs:

```
i=0;
j=0;
tabs.forEach(e => {
  if(i<50){
    i++;
    window.open(e.url, '_blank');
  }
  j++;
})
console.log("Tabs overall:"+j);
```

This will open a batch of 50 tabs from your device into the opened browser window. It also shows the overall tab count. Don't close the remaining 'empty'-tab for those developer tools and the remote device though, if you want to open another batch.
With `Ctrl + TAB` you switch through the tabs, `Ctrl +D` to bookmark them and `Ctrl+W` to close active tab. That's the way I did it manually, feel free to propose changes to this code for making everyones life's easier.

Comment: Thanks for this! -- your code above didn't work as of ``` Version 1.26.67 Chromium: 91.0.4472.114 (Official Build) (64-bit) ``` BUT, still gave me hope that Brave would work.  Got it working, and posting my code below... Ok don't have the REP for it, but here is [the console .js code ](https://jsfiddle.net/rhfbkonv/) for Brave on Android 11 as of 2021-June

Answer (score 2):

Michael identified the tab_state file, it remains to decode it.  The following script worked for me (in kitkat KSH_VERSION='@(#)MIRBSD KSH R43 2013/02/19' or xenial BASH_VERSION='4.3.46(1)-release' on a tab_state file from Chrome 49.0.2623.105), it prints out the last URL first, between the URLs it removes any unprintable byte and all following bytes, and more if needed so at least 2 bytes are removed.  Following each URL it prints a space, then the removed contiguous printable bytes if any, then a comma, then the number of other bytes removed (&said bytes within parentheses).  To print the URLs only use the commented echo command instead.

```
tab_state=/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_tabs/0/tab_state
[[ $KSH_VERSION ]]||shopt -s extglob       #set if bash
(cat $tab_state;echo)|while read -r r;do b=
   while
      q=${r%http?(s)://*}          #chip off a URL
      [[ $q = *url= ]]&&{
         p=${r%http?(s)://*url=*}  #special case URL within URL
         [[ $p = "$r" ]]||q=$p;}
      h=${r:${#q}}                 #the chip
      h=${h%%[! -~]*}              #remove unprintable&following bytes
      u=$((${#r}-${#q}-${#h}))     #no of said bytes removed
      p=$((u<b?b-u:0))             #no of more bytes to remove
      [[ $h ]];do
         echo "${h::${#h}-p} ${h:${#h}-p},$u(${r:${#r}-u})"
      #  echo "${h::${#h}-p}"
         r=$q b=2
   done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

In windows, to extract `tab_state0` from a TitaniumBackup archive (that works over rooted phones)

```
7z e TitaniumB\com.android.chrome-20180918-001302.tar.gz -so | 7z e -si -ttar tab_state0 -r
```

To get the list of tabs from `tab_state0`

```
sed -b "s/^.\{20\}//g" tab_state0 | sed -b "s/.\{6\}http/\nhttp/g" > my-tabs.md
```

---

On windows I would install https://scoop.sh/ then `scoop install busybox 7zip`

Answer (score 0):

You can now bulk-save all open tabs as bookmarks, which sync way easier and allow other export means directly on a PC'S Chrome:

- Open Chrome on Android.
- To the right of the address bar, tap Switch tabs.
- Touch and hold any tab, or tap More and then Select tabs.
- Choose the tabs you want to bookmark.
- Tap More and then Bookmark tabs.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2391819?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1#zippy=%2Cbookmark-tabs

Comment: That just bookmarks them.  It does not finish it off with hoe to export them.  Its best to make the answer complete.

Comment: Just a note that steps 3 and later won't work if Chrome's Accessibility setting "Simplified view for open tabs" is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Pitching in here that for those which run android with root,
it is possible to export all of the chrome bookmarks via adb:

`# adb shell "su - -c cat /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Bookmarks"`

The bookmarks file is in plaintext JSON format, but is permissions protected by app userid, therefore root is required to read it.

it is handy if you do not sync chrome profiles across devices \ use google login with chrome.

the location is pretty standard to all androids, the Default should be recognizable to those who tinkered with it in the past..
it has the encrypted* sqlite sessions and cookies stores.

in windows it's encrypted via DPAPI, but I have no idea about android..