# How to reopen 1000 synced Opera Tabs from a different device?

Tags: root-access, opera-browser

Last time, I could simply copy the `appstate.bin` file to the new device, as described in [this Q&A](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225695/how-to-recover-open-opera-tabs-from-backup-data-after-phone-bricked). But this time, either my backup is too old or something else changed. Copying that file has no visible effect.

However, I have synced my open tabs to Opera's servers. On my freshly reinstalled phone, I can still see the "tabs open on a different device" which is that same phone pre-reinstall. I can also view the list of open tabs on [www.sync.opera.com/tabs](https://www.sync.opera.com/tabs).

How can I get all of them open on my phone again? I don't want to manually choose each one until the 1811 tabs are opened. It is also possible for me to view the same list in opera on desktop under `opera://activity`.

I have root access on my phone.

---

Seeing the number, I'm reconsidering whether I should even bother, since I will probably never look at most of those again. But I'm still curious if there is an easy way of restoring those.

The official opera forums [don't sound like that feature exists](https://forums.opera.com/topic/26899/open-all-tabs-from-other-devices).

---

When I `right-click > save as` on the opera sync website, I get the full list in a single line of html (without newlines).
Each (I hope) entry is set up like this:

```
 <div><a class="Page_clickable__2tY0h" href="https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-5/help/bluetooth-volume-defaults-to-maximum-t3641676/amp/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow">
 <img class="Page_favicon__1jni8" src="https://www.sync.opera.com/tabs" alt="">
 <span class="Page_title__1tce_">Solved: Bluetooth volume defaults to maximum on each new connection | Android Development and Hacking</span>
 <span class="Page_url__3Wp3E">https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-5/help/bluetooth-volume-defaults-to-maximum-t3641676/amp/</span></a><hr></div>
```

So if we knew how to automatically open the tabs on the phone given the URLs, extracting them should not be too hard.