# Copy all URLs of all tabs simultaneously

Tags: chrome-for-android, url, export

I have a Samsung mobile.
I am using Google Chrome on Android.
I have opened more than 20 tabs in past 20 days.
Now, I want to copy and store all the URLs (website links) of all the opened tabs in a text format in mobile (memo)  or email all the URLs combined before closing all the tabs.

How can I do it on mobile?

Comment: Dupe of [How can I export the list of open Chrome tabs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56635/44325). Note that there are only a few solutions (and need root access) for doing it from mobile directly.

Answer (score 0):

Sync the open tabs in Chrome for Android with Chrome for PC. Once the sync is completed you would see the opened tabs of your Android under *History* section (click *Tabs from Other Devices* in left panel) **in your Chrome for PC**. Thereafter, click the three dots line in the upper right panel, choose *Open all*. Make sure to close other tabs in your Chrome for PC.

Next, install [OneTab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/onetab/chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall?hl=en) extension. Click its icon in toolbar, and it would reduce all the opened tabs into a single tab by providing hyperlinks to the recently closed tabs. You can export the URLs from *Import/Export URL* option in the right panel of that tab.

Comment: Sir , i want solution for Mobile Phone . I am using Chrome in Mobile Phone Samsung (not PC). I need a text file in mobile or email having all the opened tabs urls in it .

Comment: Yes, I have given a solution for the mobile phone. You would need a PC for that.