# Recover chrome tabs from tab_store0

Tags: chrome-for-android

I usually have a lot of tabs open in my android's Chrome. Today i've opened Chrome and instead of it loading all my tabs it just displayed a new blank tab.

I'm trying to recover them. Most of them were opened a long time ago (>1 year) so it is unpractical to scroll through history to find all of them again.

I've read on this [post](https://forums.androidcentral.com/showthread.php?t=470836&s=a7387f095df8e12f63db3bba24278356&p=5434989&viewfull=1#post5434989) that i can try replacing tab_store0 for an old "tab####" file. Indeed in `data/data/com.android.chrome/app_tabs/0` there was a `tab2131` file that is 104kB so it probably holds my lost tabs.

The thing is that even after closing chrome (force stop/kill cached process) and renaming `tab2131` to `tab_store0`whenever i open Chrome it displays just a single "new tab" and the 104kb file is gone. (I have a backup, of course)

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way i can make Chrome actually read my tabs from that file?
2. Is there a way to decode that file? I tried opening it but it is unreadable.

**What i've tried to decode the file**

I've seen in this post [how can i export the list of open chrome tabs](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56635/how-can-i-export-the-list-of-open-chrome-tabs/193858%20) some commands. But i'm new to shell/bash and all this commands stuff so i'm a little bit lost.

after running `LC_ALL=C grep -a -o 'http[[:print:]]*' tab_state0` on the adb shell i get no output and opening the file it is still unreadable.

[This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/158851/201274) suggests a command to decode the file but i'm not sure how to ru nit. I saved it as a "tabScript.sh", put it on the same folder as the tab_state0 file and ran `sh tabScript.sh`but got a lot of errors

```
...
: not foundh[19]: while
: not foundh[19]: }
: not foundh[19]: do
 ,0()
: not foundh[19]: done
(repeats)
...
```

i've also tried the `sed -i "s/.\{6\}http/\r\n\r\nhttp/g" tab_state` command and it runs normally but the file is still unreadable

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: I found out after further inspection that my files were indeed corrupted.

Comment: And is it somehow possible to recover  chrome tabs (in my case closed by accident) from chrome data?