# How can I transfer/copy open chrome tabs from an android phone to a windows pc?

Tags: chrome-for-android, windows

There is already a question regarding this exact same topic here: [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56635/how-can-i-export-the-list-of-open-chrome-tabs)

\

The reason I'm posting this query again here is because I can't comment on the answers available there since I don't have 50reps yet. I urgently need someone to please clear this up for me as it's very important. I need to format my phone and sell it asap which is why I'm asking this question

The solution mentioned by Louis Madox on the original question isn't a step by step guide and since I'm not a developer which is why I'm having trouble understanding. I have successfully opened the chrome dev tools on my pc and connected my phone. After that how do I add the line of code mentioned there in the open dev tool window? I mean exactly which option do I click? 
and since the code keeps changing for every new chrome version as added by Codebling, my chrome version on pc is 80.0.3987.163

Thank you in advance to anyone that helps me out by answering.

Comment: How about Chrome Tab Sync or TabCloud?

Comment: chrome tab sync only shows around 10 or so open phone tabs on my pc. I have around a 1000

Comment: i have 3 tabs open. i use favorites

Comment: try `adb backup com.android.chrome` https://android.stackexchange.com/q/210545