# Chrome update on android makes the application freeze. I need help transporting its hundreds of tabs

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser-tabs

Chrome updates are the worst. I've lost my tabs before when it updated, and the whole thing deleted my tabs after several times of lagging a minute after opening the app.

I fixed it by reverting to the old version, disabling updates, and being happy with the base app, along with disabling the google play services since I don't grab any other apps. But recently I had to acquire an app for something at work, and I forgot to disable google play services in time.

Now the update is causing it to lag again. I open it, I can't go to multiple tab views because it's loading, and when it finally loads, the whole thing freezes and crashes.

I have a few options I think, none of them quite certain, but beggars can't be choosers, if I want to preserve the many many tabs I have.

1: disable flags. Figure out what flags were added by the update to chrome, and disable them. Maybe this will make it bloated and less likely to crash and freeze, because the old chrome was sure just fine with the amount of tabs I had.

2: find a way to transfer/save all of my tabs before resetting the app (because the bookmarks and active tabs will all disappear when I revert updates and reinstall the old chrome.
So far, I've found this: https://dev.to/piczmar_0/when-you-never-close-tabs-on-your-mobile-chrome-browser-2boj
But I am having a LOT of trouble figuring out how to follow the instructions. I have no experience coding, and I don't know what they mean by "adb" or "bash". I've managed to set the phone to develop mode and download the android studio application, but that's the extent of things. I am just utterly confused.

Can anyone help guide me how to do it?

EDIT: I am using a windows 10 laptop.

Comment: Highly related/possible dupe: [How can I export the list of open Chrome tabs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56635/44325)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `chrome://history/syncedTabs` on another computer. All of your tabs should show.

Comment: Note: this would only work if only the Chrome was allowed to use *sync* feature prior to occurrence of the problem.