# Export Google chrome's tabs *by groups*

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser-tabs

I have been following [How can I export the list of open Chrome tabs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56635/how-can-i-export-the-list-of-open-chrome-tabs/) and was able to use Chrome's native method, to generate the tabs list. Not having tried the scripting tips yet, I saved it manually.

But the list is disordered, and not broken by tab groups (of which I have a lot...). The native sync feature discards the groups too. Is there a method to get a list of tabs from android chrome **by group**?

As a less ideal alternative, is there a way to sync/send an entire,  single group from android Chrome to the PC client?