# Location of android browsers' (Chrome and Brave) open tabs

Tags: chrome-for-android, 8.0-oreo, brave-browser

virtually all android browsers remember and load all my open tabs every time I open whatever browser I want to use.

Where is this file browsers use to reload all open tabs when restarting? Is there a way to access to it at all, even if it implies having to root my device?

Any way to export or create a list of open tabs in the form of links?

Device is huawei mediapad m5 lite

SO is EMUI 8.0.0. a equivalent to android oreo 8.0

Thanks

Comment: For accessing the app-rivate folders root is required. But as far as I know Huawei devices can not be rooted. Huawei has stopped the service that unlocks the bootloader and this is required for proper rooting of a device.

Comment: I added another duplicate link. It's about exporting Chrome tabs and some of the answers also state the location (yes, it needs root access): [1](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/104153/44325), [2](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/173710/44325), [3](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/158851/44325), [4](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/110342/44325) (though, most of them are a few years old and might be outdated)