# Can Google Chrome Tabs be accessible or exported at runtime without a PC/ADB?

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser-tabs

Just like the title suggests. I've been learning Android Development for a year now but I do not know where to approach this particular issue (It might be just impossible but I'm giving it a try).

Is there any way to export the list of open Chrome tabs (or groups) without the need for a PC? I just wanna export, say, a hundred tabs into my device without having to do it in the [script-y way](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56635/how-can-i-export-the-list-of-open-chrome-tabs/193858#193858). Or did I misunderstand the answers? I've been looking for 4 hours now without any success or breakthrough.

Comment: Assuming you've seen [How can I export the list of open Chrome tabs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56635/3573) and possibly [How can I transfer all of my open tabs in Chrome in Android to Chrome on a desktop?](https://superuser.com/q/1173850/149731) but realize that isolating on-device apps is  generally desirable (spyware, etc.) so doubtful you can get a on mobile device CSV/text file of urls as I'm not aware of any official Google Chrome API.

Comment: @MorrisonChang, I've checked all possible links that mention the PC-Android bridging using adb and retrieve tabs list that way. That can be useful for PC users. However, my idea is to retrieve that list on Android from another application. I've tried accessing Chrome's UNIX-Domain socket (where Chrome DevTools on PC seem to retrieve the lists from, I do not have much knowledge on this). But one thing for sure, Android prohibits that access due to SELinux policies. Which means only root access would allow me to actually access it (which I can't do for now to experiment further).

Comment: So in other words, I am trying to make an Android Library that reads current foreground Chrome process's tabs. I am starting to believe that cannot be achievable and there needs to be some extraordinary hack.

Comment: @Volnutt You are correct, what you are trying to do is impossible without root permissions.