# Where is the path to to the Google Chrome sqlite database on Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, sqlite

It seems like the known methods for copying open tabs out of Android Chrome no longer work (a debug interface was removed) and I'd like to see if I can squeeze the open tabs from the sqlite database.

Does anyone know where in the Android filesystem Google Chrome stores its database?

Comment: Some answers from the duplicate question ([1](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/104153/44325), [2](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/110342/44325), [3](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/158851/44325), [4](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/173710/44325), [5](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204024/44325)) refer to file-based solutions, though looks like Chrome for Android uses a text file to store the tabs, not SQLite.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad I asked this question since previous queries for "mobile chrome copy urls of all open tabs" didn't get me there.