# Where are Chrome tabs stored?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I've noticed that, if I have multiple Chrome tabs open and restart the browser, the tabs are still open.  This suggests that the tab info is stored on the hard drive somewhere.  Where is this information?

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [How can I export the list of open Chrome tabs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56635/44325). Some of the answers also mentioned the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is found in `/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_tabs`.  On my phone, with two tabs open, I see

```
0/
    tab17
    tab20
    tab_state0
```

You can confirm this by deleting those three files and restarting the browser.  The tabs will all be closed.